# Move constructor doesn't move

Tags: c++

I compiled and run the following code in Visual Studio 2013 and it printed that the content of the moved object didn't change. I know that moved object can only be destroyed or assigned from another object, so my code isn't standard complaint. But anyway ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>


struct Foo
{
    std::string str;
    std::vector<int> vec;
};


int main()
{

    Foo foo = {"abc", {1, 2, 3}};

    Foo foo2( std::move(foo) );

    std::cout << foo.str.size() << '\n' << foo.vec.size() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
3
3
```

Since both string and vector define move operators I expected my class would have synthesized move constructor that would leave moved object empty.

Comment: Works as expected with g++ 4.7.2

Comment: VS doesn't automatically generate move constructors.

Comment: Presumably you want to print the size of `foo` and `foo2`'s vectors, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/hh567368.aspx

> "Rvalue references v3.0" adds new rules to automatically generate
>   move constructors and move assignment operators under certain
>   conditions. However, this is not implemented in Visual C++ in Visual
>   Studio 2013, due to time and resource constraints.